# Are there any Date pickers for React That allow free formatted free input as well as a calendar picker

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im looking for a React Date picker that will allow the user to select a date from a calendar drop down and also the option to type in the date in the text input but i would like this input to be automatically formatted like how the html date input is formatted

```html
 <input type='date' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in our production apps. Works fine.
Have a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker